# Some buttons on the site are being highlighted even on mouse-click

Tags: support, design, focus

When selecting some of the buttons under a question or an answer using a mouse (for e.g., the Follow, Close/Reopen, Flag and Delete buttons), the button has a highlight around it, as the GIF below shows:

[image]

This is the behaviour I would expect when using the *keyboard* to select the buttons, not when using the mouse. Is this new? I don't recall the highlights being applied to the buttons on mouse-click.

This also happens for

- the Edit button on meta sites where you don't have enough reputation for suggesting an edit.
- as noted by DialFrost, a comment's Flag and Delete buttons.
- the upvote and downvote buttons.
- the bookmark button.

Comment: This happens too for the flag button for comments (there's a weird red box around it when you press it)

Comment: Yes, it's new (within hours, a day, or two). They added the CSS rule `.s-btn__unset:focus, .s-btn__link:focus, .s-btn__unset:focus-visible, .s-btn__link:focus-visible { outline-style: auto; }`

Comment: This change is probably related to: "[Announcing Design Accessibility Updates on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419586/3773011)", even though it affects more sites than just SO.

Comment: @Justin quick note the comment delete button also has it, but it's hard to activate (I randomly activated the red outline somehow)

Comment: @DialFrost It's in the primary.css style sheet. While you can download the style sheet and search through it, it's often easier to find such rules in the browser's inspector, which will show the rules which are currently applied to an element. Most browsers have the ability to explicitly set many/most [pseudo-classes](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) on an element when using their inspector. The toggles for setting those are often/usually hidden until you enable them through another UI toggle-button. In Chrome and Firefox, that toggle-button is labeled ":hov".

Comment: Are you sure it's not because of your browser and/or plugins?

Comment: I'd note that what people see, or even if they see anything, *is* browser dependent. The [`outline-style: auto;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline-style#auto) specifically allows the browser to render an outline which is browser dependent. Both Chrome and Firefox will show an outline for those controls, when they have the focus, so *most* people should see something, but I haven't double-checked other browsers.

Comment: This seems to be more of a matter of personal preference. There's really no downside to leaving it like this, and as a marginal bonus, the outline tells you that if you press enter you'll activate the button.